# How to display custom links in WordPress with wp_nav_menu?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

I'm creating an one-page custom theme. I'm struggling with a custom menu, because I want to display custom links.

I've registered menu in functions.php file

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),          
     )
   );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Then, I've displayed in header.php file like this:

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
         'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
         'container' => 'ul',
         'menu_class'=> 'd-flex main-menu'
          ) );
    ?>
```

I've added custom classes for ul tag, and that is okay. Navigation works but just for pages. When I create a page, a link for that page shows up in navigation. However, after creating custom links they don't appear in navigation.

I'm searching the Stachoverflow for some quiet time, but without success. How to resolve a described issue? Do you have an idea?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have register header menu with header-menu key and trying to get it by key of top-menu which is not possible. You have to use the header-menu key to add and get a header menu. we have updated the code. you can use this code.

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array(
     'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
     'container' => 'ul',
     'menu_class'=> 'd-flex main-menu'
    ) ); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so obvious, however sometimes I'm blind.